# locals in rails partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial, locals

I have this partial:

```
<% if flash.any? %>
  <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
    <%= render 'shared/flash_message', locals: { type: type, message: message } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

which is including this partial:

```
<div class="message-box message-box--<%= type %>">
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
  <%= message %>
</div>
```

When running that I get:

> undefined local variable or method `type' for
>
> ## <#:0x007fe510aa3c80>

It's pointing to an error where I am outputting <%= type %>  Anyone know why?

Comment: I need the type to be a part of the class name. Not to be content inside of the div. Even so, moving the output of type inside the div just to see if it works there fails too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify that you are rendering a partial to pass in the local variables.

So change

```
<%= render 'shared/flash_message', locals: { type: type, message: message } %>
```

to

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/flash_message', locals: { type: type, message: message } %>.
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% if flash.any? %>
 <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
 <%= render :partial=>'shared/flash_message', locals: { type: type, message: message } %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can render partial without using `:partial` if you are not passing any other options. i.e., The point to be noted is that explicitly specifying `:partial` is required when passing additional options such as `:layout`, `:locals` etc.
So, it should be,

```
<% if flash.any? %>
  <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
    <%= render partial: "shared/flash_message", locals: { type: type, message: message } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Ref: [Using Partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)